# Как изменить пароль для user в identity без PasswordHasher?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-3

Обновлял пароль юзеру вот таким способом

```
user.PasswordHash = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, model.Password);
```

Можно как то без passwordHasher?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение

```
await _userManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user);
await _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
```